# Angular 13 generate Component Showing Nothing to be done

Tags: components, angular-cli

While Generating New component in angular 13 through cmd
ng g c comp1

Showing "Nothing to be done"

Any suggestion....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in a project directory or not.
[see what I did.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YX7m.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

check once it is already created component. For me it is already created.